React Hook Form Trigger single value keeps re-rendering all render components
Something is making trigger not work for single value. It keeps re-rendering all Controller render components.
Our project is huge, and I can not pinpoint exactly where the issue is happening. But this has something similar happen so I was hoping someone can find the issue here and tell me what's wrong and hope that works in my case too
CodeSandbox
How to Reproduce: Open Console. Click trigger, which triggers "numberFormat". Change it to any random string and it will still cause the issue.
Issue: trigger causes numberFormat1 to re-render, when its only been prompted to trigger numberFormat.
I've debugged it and the render is running whenever trigger is ran.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
